# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main and crashing

Tags: android

```
package com.harshil.home.tictac;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int c[][];
int i, j, k = 0;
Button b[][];
TextView textView;
int player = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setBoard();
 }


 private void setBoard() {
    b = new Button[4][4];
    c = new int[4][4];


    b[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    b[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);

    b[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    b[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    b[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);

    b[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    b[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    b[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            c[i][j] = 2;
    }


    textView.setText("Click a button to start");
    //adding onclickevent for each buttons
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            b[i][j].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i, j));
            if (!b[i][j].isEnabled()) {
                b[i][j].setText("");
                b[i][j].setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
      }
   }

  class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    int x;
    int y;

    public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        textView.setText("Another player's Turn");
        if ((b[x][y].isEnabled())) {
            b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
            b[x][y].setText("O");
            c[x][y] = 0;
            textView.setText("");
            if (!checkBoard()) {
                if ((b[x][y].isEnabled())) {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    b[x][y].setText("X");
                    c[x][y] = 0;
                    textView.setText("");

                }

            }


          }


      }

       private boolean checkBoard() {

        boolean gameOver = false;
        if ((c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)
                || (c[1][2] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[1][2] == 0 && c[1][3] == 0)
                || (c[2][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0)
                || (c[3][1] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][1] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)) {
            textView.setText("Game over. player 1 wins!");
            gameOver = true;
         } else if ((c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)
                || (c[1][2] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[1][2] == 1 && c[1][3] == 1)
                || (c[2][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1)
                || (c[3][1] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][1] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)) {
            textView.setText("Game over. player 2 wins!");
            gameOver = true;
         } else {
            boolean empty = false;
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                    if (c[i][j] == 2) {
                        empty = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!empty) {
                gameOver = true;
                textView.setText("Game over. It's a draw!");
            }
        }
        return gameOver;
      }


      }
      }
```

I tried to modify for 2 players but sadly,
the build is successful but still app crashing! Did I forgot to change anything in **AndroidManifest.xml** file?

The error is

```
09-13 21:26:37.043 3730-3730/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.harshil.home.tictac, PID: 3730
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.harshil.home.tictac/com.harshil.home.tictac.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.harshil.home.tictac.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.harshil.home.tictac-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.harshil.home.tictac.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.harshil.home.tictac-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.harshil.home.tictac.MainActivity
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                            ... 14 more
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.harshil.home.tictac.MainActivity
                                                     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                            ... 13 more
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
09-13 21:26:39.082 3730-3730/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3730 SIG: 9
```

Manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.harshil.home.tictac">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>

       </manifest>
```

Comment: I m new so just wanted to get hint that does the classes i mentioned in main activity wont work in same java class? Do i need to create different activity for each of functions?

Comment: check the packages names

Comment: i kept everything as default in androidmanifest.xml is that wrong?

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: could you show your Manifest ? Did you change the buildPath ?

Comment: the package name in `<manifest>`

Comment: what should i change ? I really have no info about messing with manifest.xml so....

Comment: don't change just show what's in the tag

Comment: i updated my question.It would be gr8 if u can help me out on this 1.Does the logic seems right in rest code?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.harshil.home.tictac;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int c[][];
int i, j, k = 0;
Button b[][];
TextView textView;
int player=2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setBoard();
}


private void setBoard() {
    b = new Button[4][4];
    c = new int[4][4];


    b[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    b[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);

    b[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    b[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    b[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);

    b[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    b[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    b[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            c[i][j] = 2;
    }



    //adding onclickevent for each buttons
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            b[i][j].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i, j));
            if (!b[i][j].isEnabled()) {
                b[i][j].setText("");
                b[i][j].setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    int x;
    int y;

     public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
     }





        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (player==2){
            if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                b[x][y].setText("O");
                c[x][y] = 0;
                player++;
                if (checkBoard()){

                    player=4;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"player O 
               won",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 }

             }
          }
          if(player==3){
                if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    b[x][y].setText("X");
                    c[x][y] = 1;

                    player=2;
                    if (checkBoard()){

                        player=5;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"player X 
                    won",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                 }
               }


            }




        }




          private boolean checkBoard() {

          boolean gameOver = false;
           if ((c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)
                || (c[1][2] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[1][2] == 0 && c[1][3] == 0)
                || (c[2][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0)
                || (c[3][1] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][1] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)) {

            gameOver = true;
          } else if ((c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)
                || (c[1][2] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1)
                || (c[1][3] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[1][2] == 1 && c[1][3] == 1)
                || (c[2][1] == 1 && c[2][2] == 1 && c[2][3] == 1)
                || (c[3][1] == 1 && c[3][2] == 1 && c[3][3] == 1)
                || (c[1][1] == 1 && c[2][1] == 1 && c[3][1] == 1)) {

            gameOver = true;
          } else {
            boolean empty = false;
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                    if (c[i][j] == 2) {
                        empty = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!empty) {
                gameOver = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Game 
           Drawn",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
           }
        return gameOver;
      }


      }
```

Finally got it worked !Thanks All

Comment: Congratulations! Now you can accept your answer as Accepted Answer to close this thread.

Comment: Android is really fun!Hope i get used to it soon!